# STEP 2 2002 Statistics Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

in Siklos' book about Advanced Mathemtical Problems one question is from the 2002 Paper 2 STEP exam. Here is the problem and the solution:[image]

[image]

However, I don't understand why we can't use the following method:

Since there are $N$ many voles and $200$ of them are marked the probability of you picking a marked vole is $\frac{200}{N}$. Treating this as the chance of success we see that the probability of having 11 successes and $189$ fails is $p=(\frac{200}{N})^{11}\times(1-\frac{200}{N})^{189}\times{200\choose 11}$.

This is obviously wrong. Can somebody thoroughly explain what is wrong with this logic and how to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: The probability of success (picking a marked vole) is not constant; it is $200/N$ for the first vole picked, but not for the second.

Comment: @A.Goodier I see now. I wanted to ask you, had the probability been the same, is it correct to include the $200 \choose 11$ in the calculation or not?

Comment: Yes, it would be correct to include it.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation technique returns the probability, if you catch 200 voles [*with replacement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample#Sampling_a_dichotomous_population), that 11 will be marked. But in this problem, the sample is taken *without replacement*. This has the consequence stated in @A.Goodier's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to ask, if I was to take this into account would I expect to get the same answer?

Comment: @MathsWIzzard The only real way to take it into account is to use their method.